# "The world better prepare for when I'm a billionaire" — Why not I be or I'll be is this a future tense?

Tags: word-usage, future-tense

> The world better prepare for *when I'm a billionaire*

The text taken from song lyrics. I'm curious as to what tense this is and why not *I be* or *I'**ll** be*?

Comment: In a subordinate clause, usually the future tense is not marked by "will". For example, it is idiomatic to say "I'll start talking when you pay attention". You don't say "I'll start talking when you will pay attention", unless you are talking about his willingness to pay attention.

Comment: @user178049  That should really be an answer.

Comment: Strictly, *The world **had** better prepare for [some future event / situation]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a subordinate clause, usually future tense is not marked by *will*. This is addressed by Micheal Swan in his book, *Practical English Usage*:

> In many subordinate clauses we refer to the future with the present tenses instead of **shall/will + infinitive**.
>
> Phone me when you have time (NOT ... <s>when you**'ll have time**</s>) 
> I' ll think of you when I'm lying on the beach next week (NOT ... <s>when I**'ll be lying** on the beach</s> )

So, in your sentence, "when I'm a billionaire" refers to the future, but since it is a subordinate clause, you don't need *will*.

However, you can still use "will" to talk about someone' s willingness to do something. So the sentence below is fine:

> I'll start talking when you will pay attention